# key error when running local app example with dev_appserver.py

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gcloud

I am trying to run the [appengine-endpoints-helloendpoints-python](https://github.com/googlearchive/appengine-endpoints-helloendpoints-python) app locally using the google cloud platform SDK (which has been added to my path) using the command dev_appserver.py from the command line. It used to run perfectly, but now when I try, I get an error:

```
Error processing line 2 of
/Users/hannah/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/grpc_google_pubsub_v1-0.8.1-py2.7-nspkg.pth:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/hannah/anaconda3/envs/py27/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 161, in addpackage

  exec line
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

KeyError: 'google'


Remainder of file ignored
```

It's in a anaconda python2.7 environment. I've tried looking in `site.py` but I can't follow it back to a clear missing link.

The `appcfg.py` command used to deploy from the command line doens't work at all anymore. The command is not found.

```
bash: appcfg.py: command not found
```

As I said, I reinstalled and authorised the google cloud SDK and it is added to my path and that hasn't solved anything.

Oh finally, the error comes up whenever I run the `dev_appserver.py` command, not just with the example code from google.

Any tips would be appreciated

Comment: It's not clear from the details you provided what is actually the issue here.  The issue could be with the sample code (as the example you've linked is deprecated), from the App Engine SDK, the Google Cloud SDK or from the Anaconda Python2.7 environment.  What results do you get when running the [Python Hello World](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/quickstart#hello_world_code_review) for App Engine?  If this fails, I would definitely look at installing the [**original App Engine SDK**](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/download) and then using `appcfg.py`.